# Regex, extract word before and after another one

Tags: python, regex

Hello i have problem to extract specific word from text using regex.
lines:

```
limk ab1
limk ab2 helo
rest helo
ab3 limk helo
ab4 limk
```

I need 3 letter word as output only when `limk` is before or after this word that I am looking for, and also if `limk` is before it should be at the begining of the line, if its after - should be at the end of the line. In this line should be only limk and value that i am looking for.

expected  output:

```
ab1
ab4
```

my regex:

```
r'(^[0-9a-zA-Z]{3} \blimk\b)|(\blimk\b [0-9a-zA-Z]{3}$)'
```

someone can explain how i should correct it?
thanks

Comment: Try `(?m)^([0-9a-zA-Z]{3})\s+limk\b|\blimk\s+([0-9a-zA-Z]{3})$`, see https://regex101.com/r/hNMlwd/1

Comment: Why not `ab2` ? See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/MT0Wpo/1)

Comment: @bobble bubble ive edited your regex to `(?<=^limk\s)[a-z\d]{3}$|[a-z\d]{3}(?=\slimk$)` and its working now , thanks

Comment: @sygneto You were addressing me, right? `(?<=^limk\s)[a-z\d]{3}$` won't work if there are 2 or more spaces between `limk` and the word.

Comment: See the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57803264/3832970) with explanation and sample usage code.

Comment: If you would not accept `ab2` then don''t you think your description should explicitly state that there can only be two words on the line (including `limk`)?

Comment: Yes Ronald i edited my question, sory all for my mistake, i forgot to add that"In this line should be only limk and value that i am looking for."

Comment: I edited [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57803264/3832970), the regex is now fully optimized. Note you should not repeat anchors all around the pattern, use DRY approach as I showed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^([0-9a-zA-Z]{3})\s+limk$|^limk\s+([0-9a-zA-Z]{3})$
```

1. ^ Matches the beginning of the line
2. [0-9a-zA-Z]{3} Matches upper and lower case ascii characters plus digits of length 3
3. \s+ Matches 1 or more spaces
4. matches limk
5. $ Matches the end of the line
6. | Start of the second alternative:
7. ^ Matches the start of the line
8. Matches limk
9. \s+ Matches one or more spaces
10. [0-9a-zA-Z]{3} Matches upper and lower case ascii characters plus digits of length 3
11. $ Matches the end of the line

The code:

```
import re

s = """limk ab1
limk ab2 helo
rest helo
ab3 limk helo
ab4 limk"""

matches = [x[0] if x[0] != '' else x[1] for x in re.findall(r'(?m)^([0-9a-zA-Z]{3})\s+limk$|^limk\s+([0-9a-zA-Z]{3})$', s)]
for match in matches:
    print(match)
```

Prints:

```
ab1
ab4
```

[See Demo](https://ideone.com/39wkas)

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want:

`^(\w{3}) limk$|^limk (\w{3})$`

https://regex101.com/r/S1OMmi/2

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
(?m)^(?:limk\s+([a-zA-Z0-9]{3})|([a-zA-Z0-9]{3})\s+limk)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/551A6e/2).

**Details**

- `(?m)` - make the anchors match at the linefeeds
- `^` - start of a line
- `(?:` - start of a containering non-capturing group (to apply anchors to all alternatives):

  - `limk` -  `limk` at the end of the line
  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
  - `([0-9a-zA-Z]{3})` - Capturing group 1: three alnum chars
- `|` - or

  - `([0-9a-zA-Z]{3})` - Capturing group 2: three alnum chars
  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
  - `limk` - a `limk` word
- `)` - end of the grouping
- `$` - end of string.

[Python code](https://ideone.com/SZhLiy):

```
import re
rx = re.compile(r"^(?:limk\s+([a-zA-Z0-9]{3})|([a-zA-Z0-9]{3})\s+limk)$", re.M)
s = "limk ab1\nlimk ab2 helo\nrest helo\nab3 limk helo\nab4 limk"
print (["{}{}".format(x,y) for x,y in rx.findall(s)])
# => ['ab1', 'ab4']
```

Comment: @RonaldAaronson Thanks, I swapped the logic a bit. Fixed the answer.